# FLask(SqlAlchemy) -SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '0'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm getting this error when i try to create a SQL statement by using SQLAlchemy in Flask. I'm using hybrid properties and trying to use hybrid properties when i construct a query with query_entities.

```
daily_stats = (
 MyModel.query.with_entities(
        MyModel.purchases,
        MyModel.visits)
 )
```

--

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '0
```

I create the field "purchases" as a hybrid_field and it's always 0 in my model and that causes the problem.

```
class MyModel(Model):
     visits=Column(db.Numeric)

     @hybrid_property
    def purchases(self):
        return 0

    @visits.expression
    def purchases(cls):
    return 0
```

is there a way to convert integer to sql alchemy column or what would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

you can return sql expression instead of phyton data structure via

```
    return select([0])
```

then you can use this as part of your query.with_entities statement